RISC-V: What would be the Impact of Swapping Bit Positions in Branch and Jump Instruction Formats?
I am working with RISC-V instruction formats, and I am considering making some adjustments to the bit positions in the Branch (B-type) and Jump (J-type) instruction formats. Specifically:
Branch (B-type): Swapping the positions of imm[12] (bit 31) and imm[11] (bit 7).
Jump (J-type): Swapping the positions of imm[20] (bit 31) and imm[11] (bit 20).
The motivation behind this is to make the immediate value fields more contiguous, potentially simplifying the instruction decoding and making the hardware implementation more straightforward.
Here’s a visual representation of the current instruction formats:
Branch (B-type):
31      30-25     24-20   19-15   14-12   11-7             6-0
imm[12] imm[10:5] rs2     rs1     funct3  imm[4:1] imm[11] opcode

Jump (J-type):
31      30-21     20      19-12      11-7   6-0
imm[20] imm[10:1] imm[11] imm[19:12] rd     opcode

I’m wondering if these changes would be beneficial in practice, and if there are any drawbacks or unforeseen issues that could arise from such a modification, particularly in terms of hardware implementation, toolchain support, or software compatibility.
For what reason was these two types designed this way, did they deliberately placed the highest bit of the immediate numbers at the highest bit? That would be a little bit confusing to read and compile, but what would be the benefit for it?


Would swapping these bit positions simplify instruction decoding in hardware, or would it introduce new complexities - unlikely. 2) Are there any potential impacts on software tools (e.g., assemblers, compilers) and existing RISC-V codebases? - yes. It will simply break them all. You are changing the basic ISA, it becomes a new architecture.


I mean, would it be better if these two types were designed this way? or did they deliberately put the highest bit at the highest position of the command, for what reason?

I'd say the considerations when designing the command format are mostly hardware-driven. So yes, they might have had some considerations in mind which are likely rooted in designing a simpler hardware. But this specific choice might be just arbitrary, except that it is logical to have higher bits at higher positions. For sure, it wasn't impacted by any "existing" software at the time of the definition.

Note that these instructions sign extend the immediate so you need to fill the top bits with a copy of the MSB. It might be more efficient routing wise this way.

Those changes would seem to be undoing some carefully thought out design benefits for the hardware, especially small, low end, low power market.

@GlofriTinplo The RISC-V specification explicitly gives explanations for why immediate values are laid out how they are, including why the top bit is always used in the way it is.

@ThomasJager And in fact there's a Q&A from a few years ago about it, with answers quoting the spec: Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?
